# Loop through a CSV file and verify column count for each row

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and have been trying to loop through a CSV file and return column count of each row. Compare that column count to the first row and have something happen it its not equal. In this case replace comma with nothing. Then create a new file with the changes.

```
$csvColumnCount = (import-csv "a CSV file" | get-member -type NoteProperty).count

$CurrentFile = Get-Content "a CSV file" |
ForEach-Object { $CurrentLineCount = import-csv "a CSV file" | get-member -type NoteProperty).count
    $Line = $_ 
    if ($csvColumnCount -ne $CurrentLineCount)
         { $Line -Replace "," , "" }
    else
         { $Line } ; 
    $CurrentLineCount++} | 
Set-Content ($CurrentFile+".out")
Copy-Item ($CurrentFile+".out") $ReplaceCSVFile
```

Comment: I think its not counting the number of columns correctly for each row. The test CSV file i am using has a few rows with less than the header row column. The script is removing commas within the entire file.

Comment: You want to test if any property in a row is empty or missing? Then alter those rows?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by property. I just want to test the column count. i.e. If the first Row in the file has 8 columns (header row) and 10th row only has 9 columns, I want to alter only the 10th row.

Comment: You should give an example of your input file. A method of approach can be to correct the file before reading it with Import-Csv.

Comment: Hmm. Looks to me like you are defining the csvColumnCount and CurrentLineCount to be identical. Also looks to be missing an open paren on the line where CurrentLineCount is defined.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you are trying to achieve. Seemingly the purpose is to detect rows that have insufficient values on them. These rows then have all commas removed, effectively making them into single-value rows. The resulting file will be a mix of 'good' lines and lines with single values. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is to check which rows of a CSV file are invalid then just use a simple split and count, something like so:

```
$csv = Get-Content 'your_file.csv'
$count = ($csv[0] -split ',').count
$csv | Select -Skip 1 | % {
  if(($_ -split ',').count -eq $count) {
    ...do valid stuff
  } else {
    ...do invalid stuff
  }
}
```

For CSV checking purposes avoid CSV cmdlets because these will have a tendency to try and correct problems, for example:

```
$x = @"
a,b,c
1,2,3,4
"@

$x | ConvertFrom-Csv

>  a b c
   - - -
   1 2 3
```

Also I think the flow of your code is a little confused. You trying to return the results of a pipeline to a variable called $CurrentFile whilst at the other end of that pipeline you are trying use the same variable as a file name for Set-Content.

If your CSV has quoted fields which could contain commas then a simple split will not work. If that is the case a better option would be to use a regex to break each line into columns which can then be counted. Something like this:

```
$re = '(?:^|,)(?:\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)'
$csv = Get-Content 'your_file.csv'
$count = [regex]::matches($csv[0], $re).groups.count
$csv | Select -Skip 1 | % {
  if([regex]::matches($_, $re).groups.count -eq $count) {
    ...do valid stuff
  } else {
    ...do invalid stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: In place of `$csv[1..($csv.count - 1)]` .... `$csv | Select -Skip 1 | %` seems much simpler